# Replacing multiple columns with values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am replacing multiple columns values in pandas with the `pd.DataFrame.replace` method, however, this will not update any values inside my loop, and I cannot understand why it wont.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                    'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                    'C': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})


operators = { 'A':{ 0 : 2 } , 'B': { 5 : 8 }, 'C': None }
for keys, values in operators.items():
    if values == None:
        continue
    else:
        for existing, new in values.items():
            if keys == 'A' and new is not None:
                print(keys, existing, new)
                df.replace({keys: existing}, new)
            elif keys == 'B' and new is not None:
                df.replace({keys: existing}, new)
            else:
                df.replace({keys: existing}, new)
```

Will print the exact same values for the dataframe.

Comment: Use `inplace=True` option for [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html).

Comment: `keys == 'operator'`? the keys are 'A' 'B' 'C'

Comment: What‥ are‥ you doint? Do you really need that loop?

Comment: @user19077881 my bad It was based on my dataset with thos ekeys

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your replacements. That means you should either do:

- put `inplace=True`

```python
df.replace({keys: existing}, new, inplace=True)
```

- save the replacement back to `df` without inplace

```python
df = df.replace({keys: existing}, new)
```

### Loop

Anyway, why do you need that monstrous  loop?
You can simply pass a `dict` to [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), it works like a charm.
It does not support `'C': None` though, as the dictionary should either be value to value for all columns `{0:2, 5:8}` or column value to value as you have it for 'A' and 'B'.
Let's get rid of your `None` and do the replacement in one go:

```python
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                    'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                    'C': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
operators = { 'A':{ 0 : 2 } , 'B': { 5 : 8 }, 'C': None }

# df = df.replace({k:v for k,v in operators.items() if v!=None})
df.replace({k:v for k,v in operators.items() if v!=None}, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

###### Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  2  8  a
1  1  6  b
2  2  7  c
3  2  8  d
4  2  9  e
```